# Problem with loading remote XML file

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'm trying to load a remote xml file using php.

This is my code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($this->xml_file);
$file = $doc->getElementsByTagName('file');
$totalFiles = $file->length;
echo $totalFiles;
```

The remote xml file link is:

`http://localhost/script/index.php?act=xml`

This is the code in `index.php`:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><MultimediaGallery>';

$query = mysql_query('SELECT `id`,`image`,`desc` FROM `'
          .confitem('database','prefix').'table` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT '
          .$start.','.$limit);
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $img = unserialize($result['image']);
    $desc = unserialize($result['desc']);
    $xml .= '<file type="photo"><thumb>'
      .settings('site','url').'/'.OPATH_APPFOLDER.'/'
      .OPATH_UPFOLDER.'/wallpapers/thumbs/'.$img[0].'</thumb><source>'
      .settings('site','url')
      .'/'.OPATH_APPFOLDER.'/'.OPATH_UPFOLDER
      .'/wallpapers/'.$img[0].'</source><description>'
      .$desc[$_SESSION['languagecode']].'</description></file>';
}

$xml .= '</MultimediaGallery>';
header("content-type: text/xml");
echo $xml;
```

When I visit this xml file link direct in the browser .. it's output to me xml file with this style :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><MultimediaGallery><file type="photo"><thumb>http://localhost/script/application/data/wallpapers/thumbs/1116205566_42ce0841ab_s.jpg</thumb><source>http://localhost/script/application/data/wallpapers/1116205566_42ce0841ab_s.jpg</source><description>dfdfdfdf</description></file></MultimediaGallery>
```

When I execute the xml function which uses the dom to load the xml file I get this error:

> Warning: DOMDocument::load()
>   [domdocument.load]: Extra content at
>   the end of the document in
>   http://localhost/script/index.php,
>   line: 2 in
>   C:\AppServ\www\script\application\libraries\wallpapers\multimedia.class.php
>   on line 46

Why is this happening?

**Update:**

I used dom to create the xml instead:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$root  =  $xml->createElement('MultimediaGallery');
$xml->appendChild($root); 

$query = mysql_query('SELECT `id`,`image`,`desc` FROM `'.confitem('database','prefix').'backgrounds` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT '.$start.','.$limit);
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {
  $img   = unserialize($result['image']);
  $desc  = unserialize($result['desc']);
  $element = $xml->createElement('file');
  $root->appendChild($element);
  $attr  =  $xml->createAttribute('type');
  $element->appendChild($attr);
  $attr_text = $xml->createTextNode('photo');
  $attr->appendChild($attr_text);

  $thumb  = $xml->createElement('thumb');
  $element->appendChild($thumb);
  $thumb_text = $xml->createTextNode(settings('site','url').'/'.OPATH_APPFOLDER.'/'.OPATH_UPFOLDER.'/wallpapers/thumbs/'.$img[0]);
  $thumb->appendChild($thumb_text);

  $source  = $xml->createElement('source');
  $element->appendChild($source);
  $source_text = $xml->createTextNode(settings('site','url').'/'.OPATH_APPFOLDER.'/'.OPATH_UPFOLDER.'/wallpapers/'.$img[0]);
  $source->appendChild($source_text);

  $description  = $xml->createElement('description');
  $element->appendChild($description);
  $description_text = $xml->createTextNode($desc[$_SESSION['languagecode']]);
  $description->appendChild($description_text);
 }

header("content-type: text/xml");
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

But it still gives me the same error. I noticed some thing though, I tried to copy my output xml and save it in a file and read it using the dom parser and the result was that it's read successfully.

But when I try parsing the xml output by the php file then it throws an error.

Comment: Try trimming the output?

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not well-formed. E.g there is something wrong with it.

Try to avoid making XML by concatenating strings because this will happen. You can use DomDocument you make XML as well as read it and manipulate it.

Make sure you have no leading or trailing white space in your XML generating script.

You should also be using `CDATA`